# $\lim_{x\to 0}x^a\log^k(x)$ where $a>0,k\in\mathbb N_0$

Tags: limits, functions, logarithms, indeterminate-forms

I'd know how to solve this for $k=0$ or $k=1$ for example, but I'm currently lost trying to prove the limit is zero for any non-negative integer $k$. I'd appreciate any hints!

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to 0}x^a\log^k(x)$ is also equal to$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(-1)^k (log(\frac{1}{x}))^k}{\frac{1}{x^a}}$$, which turns indeterminancy to infinity/infinity form.
There are now two approaches,First you may apply L'Hospitals rule to get the answer.
Secondly, by graphical method you may see that POLYNMIAL growth as "h"(substituted as 1/x is this case, thus making limit h tending towards infinity), is far greater than logarithmic growth as "h tends towards infinity", therefore denomitor is far greater than numerator thus making limit tending to zero

Comment: I also tried L'Hospital's rule, but applying it once gives me $(-1)^k\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log^k\left(\frac1x\right)}{x^{-a}}=\frac ka(-1)^k\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log^{k-1}\left(\frac1x\right)}{x^{-a+1}}$ and I don't see how this gets me any closer to a result.

Comment: for simplification substitute 1/x to h, and limit x tends to zero to limit h tends to infinity.

Comment: For clear cut understanding, i recommend graphical method, because sometimes(not in ths case) differentiation is not pretty.